# Same entity query produces different SQL queries on different servers

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I am querying an entity data model (.NET 4.0), and getting wildly different results when run locally vs. running from our development server. Locally the query takes 10 seconds, but on the dev server it's taking 7 minutes. Both environments are hitting the same SQL 2005 database (i.e. same exact connection string).

I took a look at the underlying SQL generated, and found that it's different for the two environments. The query generated by the code on the dev server has some extra sub-queries that are causing the dramtic slowdown. So what would cause each environment's SQL code generator to produce different results for what should be the same query?

**UPDATE - (Removed old sample because it was misleading)**

I found the cause of the slowness, but I still don't understand why the same code base operating against the same database is producing two different SQL queries.

What's happening is that when I run the code locally, all the constant strings in my query are placed in the SQL query string as normal strings. When I run the same code on the server, the SQL that's generated turns my strings into Unicode strings:

Generated locally:

> WHERE ( 'DENY' <> [Extent1].[status] )

Generated on the server:

> WHERE ( N'DENY' <> [Extent1].[status] )

Adding and removing the "N" notation for Unicode on the strings dramatically changes the execution time. So now I know WHY the query is slow, but I still don't know why the SQL code generator on the server is making these strings Unicode, but when run locally it's not. I checked the entity data model, and the "status" column has it's Unicode property set to False, so I don't know why the query would ever convert to Unicode.

Comment: Can you show the differences between queries?

Comment: Possibly missing indexes or fk relationships?

Comment: I'm not concerned with overall performance, I just want to know why it's generating different queries. The database itself isn't optimal, but it's not ours so I can't fiddle with indexes, FK's, etc.

Comment: are both servers advertising the same version numbers, etc?

Comment: @cgatian : the OP said "same connection string". But it will not the first to confound prod and dev connection string!

Comment: @gfrizzle : I don't want to analyze performance. Seeing the difference is a good start to investigate why you have such a weird comportement.

Comment: @MarcGravell : Version numbers for what?

Comment: @gfrizzle as in: are they the same version of sql server

Comment: @MarcGravell : Yes, both code bases are pointing at the exact same database.

Comment: @gfrizzle k; are they the same .NET version / EF version etc?

Comment: @MarcGravell : I don't have control over the server, but I had our admin install the latest .NET 4.0 and EF, but it didn't help. I really thought that would be the issue.

Comment: @gfrizzle what is the exact .NET version installed on the two servers? for example, does your dev server actually have .NET 4.5 installed on it? .NET 4.5 is an over-the-top install, not a side-by-side install, so if the dev server has 4.5, then .NET 4.0 code is still actually using the 4.5 dlls.

Comment: @MarcGravell : Locally I have .NET 4.5 installed, but the app is targetting 4.0 because the server is still using IIS6. The server does not have 4.5 installed. Could that be the issue? Can I assume that installing 4.5 wouldn't have any adverse affects to existing apps on that server?

Comment: It sounds like you are running two versions of SQL server.  One locally on your machine (SQL Express) and one for production (SQL Server).  Can you confirm this?  What is the version of SQL server running on your machine?

Comment: @grfizzle yes the .net 4.5 locally can change the behaviour even when targeting 4.0 - so I that is very likely to be related

Comment: @Josh the OP stated same server

Comment: @MarcGravell : Hit an interesting snag. The web server is 2003, so .NET 4.5 can't be installed on it. I'm not sure there's a solution to cover that scenario, short of getting one of the web servers upgraded.

Comment: @gfrizzle a bit of advice: if you are targeting server 2003, then make your dev environment server 2003. Hyper-V (or any other VM tool) is a good way to do that if you still want to use a desktop OS rather than a server OS.

Comment: @gfrizzle I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Did you ever find a workaround?